# How to tell what/who is preventing an object from being garbage collected (C#)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I've been working on a C#/WPF application for a little while now and I've gotten to the point where I think some of my objects are not being garbage collected as i would expect them to be.

How did I make this determination?

I've added finalizers with a break point in the classes I expect to be garbage collected.  I run my application and trigger the series of events that would a) create the object and then b) cause the object to be condemned (in theory).  For example, I open a dialog and then close it, etc.  My finalizers are not being called.

Just to be extra sure that GC isn't taking an inordinately long time or that the objects somehow got promoted into and older generation and hence are not being collected at the same rate I even created a thread that periodically forces garbage collection i.e.:

```
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Still no finalizer breakpoints being hit.  At this point I'm fairly certain that there is some reference preventing these objects from being collected but I can't for the life of me determine what.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Are my results valid based on my testing?
2. If so is there some
   mechanism or tool that I can use to determine object references
   (i.e. a visual representation of the object reference chain)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the destructor doesn't run because  memory isn't needed. The garbage collector decides when it is necessary to free memory.

Comment: Have you tried using the memory profiler in Visual Studio? I assume it works for your project type.

Comment: The memory profiler is showing me allocations and usage but what I need to find out is who is hold the reference to a particular object.  I can see the profiler being useful for determining performance but I can't seem to get the detailed information I'm looking for ( I do not dispute that my knowledge of how to use the profiler tool effectively may be lacking...)

Comment: Don't try to verify this in the Debugger - it can extend the lifetime of objects. Run a RElase verson and use logging.

Comment: Post the relevant code (an outline). So far you have not demonstrated that there is any problem here.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an exact answer to your question, as I can't see your code - but I find most commonly for me, when an object doesn't get garbage collected its usually because I have forgotten to unsubscribe from an event somewhere. When you subscribe to an event you do create a reference that will prevent your class from being collected.

On a side note, the garbage collector is a very unpredictable process. I remember reading somewhere that even if you call `GC.Collect` it does not guarantee that your unreferenced class will get collected immediately.

Comment: That is what I expect but for the life of me I can't find any event subscriptions that I'm not unsubscribing :(

Answer (score 0):

By calling `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers`, you are ensuring the finalizers will kick off, but you also need to be sure that this code is calling. Breakingpoint *it* (or rather, the method closure right after `WaitForPendingFinalizers`) to ensure that the code is being executed.

Since this is a WPF project, it may also be helpful to insert a "debug button" by having a `PreviewKeyDown` in whatever view ou're working on, which cheks for a specific key and then breakpoints in an otherwise no-op `if`. Putting your garbage collection code here should similarly ensure that your code is executing.

As mentioned, event handlers can also hard references, so be aware of everywhere you're using events, and realize that WPF hooks into `PropertyChanged` quite a bit.

Comment: I've done that.  So I can verify that I am forcing the GC process but I'm not  seeing my finalizers get hit.  So I'm confident that there is a reference somewhere.  I guess the main thing I'm trying to find at this point is how to tell who is holding the references

Comment: Well, your IDE should allow you to search for any and all references for any and all objects. It's been a while since I used Visual Studio myself but I'd imagine it allows you to do just that. MonoDevelop does.

Just go over the references to whichever object(s) you feel should be collected that aren't and see if you can figure out if any of those are preventing the collection. Basically, it's a process of elimination.